# External functions calling other functions in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Can External functions call the internal functions, private functions and the public function of the same contract in their body in Solidity?

Comment: Yes (they would be almost useless otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The `external` modifier only changes how the function itself may be called, it does not affect the execution of the function with respect to calling other methods.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can as long as those functions does not change the state of the contract. Completely for get purposes only.

Comment: Everything after the first word in this answer is wrong!

Comment: @goodvibration Saying this is wrong without an argument is much more wrong. Whilst in my opinion this has a valid point

Comment: @keysl: It's just wrong. Not a lot more to say. The visibility of a function (private / internal / external / public) and the mutability of a function (pure / view / neither) are two independent characteristics. The only argument to defend it with is that an external function can only call private/internal/public functions of the same mutability level or "lower" (e.g., view can call only view and pure, pure can call only pure, etc). But this argument is a very weak defense-line, since the question is not about mutability levels.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm sorry if it caused a misunderstanding. But what I intend to say with for viewing purposes only is to display or just get something, I was not talking about mutability. Hence, I edited my post to hopefully make it less confusing. If you still find it wrong, please, feel free to correct me. I would highly appriciate that.

Comment: You haven't changed anything (except "view" to "get"). The answer is still wrong. A non-constant external function can call non-constant internal/private/public functions (which DO change the state of the contract).